# Headless Chrome - trigger callback from loaded webpage

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, google-chrome-devtools, headless-browser

Is there a way to trigger a callback from the loaded webpage? I used to use PhantomJS where it was possible using following code:

```
 if (typeof window.callPhantom === 'function') {
    window.callPhantom({ data: 'RenderPDF' });
 }
```

And in the phantomjs script:

```
page.onCallback = function (data) {
   /* callback code */
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can evaluate javascript on the browser by using the evaluate function in the [Runtime domain](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime/).

Example below evaluates a function which returns a promise which will be resolved when `window.callChrome` is called.

```
function callChrome() {
  return () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      window.callChrome = resolve;
    });
  });
}

// runtime is located in the client object
Runtime.evaluate({
  expression: `(${callChrome()})()`,
  awaitPromise: true,
}).then((result) => {
  // what you've passed into the window.callChrome function.
});
```

The expression that is evaluated looks like this.

```
(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.callChrome = resolve;
  });
})()
```

You should really run this piece of code once the page is ready. Ideally using the `Page.loadEventFired` function.